# ie7 get meta language content with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7, meta-tags, head

I run the following line of jquery.

`var language = $('meta[http-equiv=content-language]').attr("content");`

The relevand part of the html is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
```

Its working fine in every tested browser except IE7 where it return `undefined`.

Is it possible to get it working in IE7?

thx

Comment: Does this have any effect? I would think by the time jQuery runs the browser would have already parsed the metatags.

Comment: This is a multilanguage site and i need to know what is the current language because of translation things and interaction with the database.

Comment: Sorry, I read the code wrong, i thought you were trying to set the value, not get it :)